# Landroid.os.Parcelable ClassCastException

Tags: android

In an Android application, I'm trying to extract an extra from a Bundle like the following:

```
Parcelable p = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("android.nfc.extra.NDEF_MESSAGES");
```

But I get the following exception

```
Key android.nfc.extra.NDEF_MESSAGES expected Parcelable but value was a [Landroid.os.Parcelable;.  The default value <null> was returned.
Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1179)
    at com.example.nfcmessenger.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:77)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2321)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is this `Landroid.os.Parcelable`? The normal import for Parcelable is just `android.os.Parcelable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES) states:

> Extra containing an array of `NdefMessage` present on the discovered tag.
>
> This extra is mandatory for `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` intents, and optional for `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED`, and `ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED` intents.
>
> When this extra is present there will always be at least one `NdefMessage` element. Most NDEF tags have only one NDEF message, but we use an array for future compatibility.
>
> Constant Value: "android.nfc.extra.NDEF_MESSAGES"

It seems that you are retrieving an array of Parcelable objects, not a single object.
Change your code to something like:

```
Parcelable[] pArray = intent.getExtras().getParcelableArray("android.nfc.extra.NDEF_MESSAGES");    
Parcelable p = pArray[0];
```